# How to implement Merge sort starting from 0?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm reading Introduction to algorithms - Third edition and I'm stuck in the Merge-sort problem. I want to implement the algorithm on C#. As we know, or not, nevermind, structures in the book are described by first index of 1 (not 0 as we expected). The following code is presented in the book:

```
  Merge(A, p, q, r)
n1 = q - r + 1;
n2 = r - q
let L[1..n1 + 1] and R[1..n2 + 1] be new arrays
**for** i = 1 **to** n1
    L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
**for** j = 1 **to** n2
    R[j] = A[q + j]
L[n1 + 1] = infinity
R[n2 + 2] = infinity
i = 1
j = 1
**for** k = p **to** r
    **if** L[i] <= R[j]
              A[k] = L[i]
              i++
    **else** A[k] = R[j]
              j++
```

I'm really confused with all these sentinels and stuff but the most important problem is: If we get the situation when our p(startIndex) is equal to 0 then what's happening below. When we fill the left array L[], on the first iteration (i = 0), we are receiving `IndexOutOfRangeException`, because `L[0] = A[0 + 0 - 1]`. Is there someone who can explain me whats the solution when your starting index is 0?

Comment: You should at least explain what this pseudo code is meant to do part by part. For example what are the arguments: arrays, random numbers or whatever?

Comment: @Fuex: such algorithms can be transformed for a change of index origin in a mechanical way; there is no real need to understand the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your program in a systematic way.

Assume this dummy code:

```
let A[1..N], B[1..M]
for i= 1 to N
    for j= i to M
        A[i]= B[j]
```

Shift all array accesses with a `-1` before the `]`:

```
let A[0..N-1], B[0..M-1]
for i= 1 to N
    for j= i to M
        A[i-1]= B[j-1]
```

You can stop here if you want. You can also shift the index variables, blindly replacing `k` by `k+1`:

```
let A[0..N-1], B[0..M-1]
for i+1= 1 to N ' Caution, this is syntactically wrong
    for j+1= i+1 to M ' Caution, this is syntactically wrong
        A[i+1-1]= B[j+1-1]
```

Rewrite the for clauses and simplify:

```
let A[0..N-1], B[0..M-1]
for i= 0 to N-1
    for j= i to M-1
        A[i]= B[j]
```